# Positioning of pseudo-elements like :after in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Consider the following HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th class="title">Test title</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

And the following CSS:

```
table {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

th.title {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

th.title::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    content: '>';
}
```

See the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/63EZB/1.

What I want is the greater than sign to appear on the right side of the `th`. The code above works both in Chrome and IE8+, but not in Firefox (28). Firefox positions the sign absolutely on the window's right, like the `relative` position of the `th` element isn't considered.

What's going wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/63EZB/4/ This works on both

Comment: The problem is that your th is with display: inline instead block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for something like this **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/63EZB/5/)**

CSS:

```
th.title::after {       
    margin-right: 5px;
    float:right;
    content:'>';
}
```

Comment: Nice and elegant/better solution. Can you explain why this float doesn't have to be cleared?

Answer (score 0):

Try with theses rules :

```
th.title:after {
   position:relative;
   float:right;
   right: 5px;
   content: '>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it (I rarely work with tables) table elements don't mix well with absolute or relative positioning.

I would simply put a holding div inside the th and give that the position relative and the pseudo element.

This could also give you some ideas: http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/